# Print in new line in a file using shebang script

Tags: shell, unix, shebang

i have below code to print the QUERY_STRING data to text file in new line

```
         #!/bin/sh
         echo "Content-type: text/html"
         echo ""
         read QUERY_STRING
         echo $QUERY_STRING > /test
         eval $(echo "$QUERY_STRING"|awk -F'\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}')
         echo ""
         echo ""
```

But when i see the test file, its not printing new line, can you please say how to get it print in new line in

```
        eval $(echo "$QUERY_STRING"|awk -F'\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}')
```

i gave -F'\n' but its not working. Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
eval $(echo "$QUERY_STRING"|awk -F'\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i, "\n"}}')
```